# Compensation for late arrival of flight

Tags: air-travel, delays, compensation

I am trying to book a train or bus from one of the London terminals to Edinburgh on 2nd July.

I will be arriving at LHR by flight from Bangalore in Air India airline. I will have checked in luggage. Suppose my flight scheduled arrival at LHR is 1 PM and I book ticket from London by 3 PM and flight arrives late in LHR and I miss the train/bus, do I get some refund from airlines?

What is the procedure? How much can I get? Do I get it in the spot?

Comment: From where do the flight depart? In general you have not compensation for train/taxi etc, but a generic compensation (which it is hard to get). And no, less then two hours delay are not considered exceptional, and immigration could be very very slow in London.

Comment: So, what do you think is reasonable time to book a flight if scheduled arrival at lhr is 1PM @GiacomoCatenazzi

Comment: From where? From Paris, or from Sydney?  Personally, I would check flights that go further north (connecting or not). For strange reasons [LHR slots], there are few nearly empty flight (and they cost less than main flight).

Comment: That depends on a lot of things. Where do you live (i.e. will you have to go through immigration) what airline, will you have checked-in luggage that you have to wait for, ...

Comment: Why not take another flight from LHR to Edinburgh? If you can get them on the same ticket it will be the airline's responsibility to take care of you and rebook you if your first flight is delayed. And in some circumstances it might even be cheaper. You may also check connections via other cities.

Comment: Not that even if the flight is on time, 2 hours from opening of the aircraft door at LHR to onboard a train at King's Cross seems awfully short to me, especially if you are in coach, coming from abroad, with a non-EU passport, have checked luggage, are unfamiliar with the local layout, and so on. Just getting out of the airport may take you an hour (possibly a lot more if passport control is backed up), and the travel from LHR to Kings Cross will take around one hour using public transport, plus waiting time, time to buy tickets, etc. This is waaaaaay to short for comfort.

Comment: @jcaron I have already booked a flight to London and I thought I can book a cheap flight from London to Edinburgh.. it seems that I made a mistake.. :D i am planning to book  with a gap of 6 hours.. does it look ok?

Comment: You can always try to check with the airline if they could make a change to add a connection to Edinburgh. Depending on airline and fare, it might or might not be possible. Not that even with a small change fee it may make sense. 6 hours from LHR to King's Cross seems to be plenty. But your best option is probably to try to find a flexible fare for your train so you can take the first train that leaves after you get to the train station.

Comment: @jcaron ok, I did not thought about asking airlines if they could make a change to add a connection to Edinburgh... I will call them..

Comment: At the relevant times there are fast trains from Kings Cross to Edinburgh every half hour. If you follow @jcaron's suggestion of a flexible fare you will not wait long for a train.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan ok ok. Thanks for the information... :)

Comment: Just to clarify, your "ticket from London" is from one of the London terminals or from Heathrow?

Comment: @gerrit From one of the London terminals.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Then two hours is too short for sure, six hours is safe and you can even look around London for a bit if you have some time to spare.

Comment: Whether you can travel on a later train depends on the type of ticket you have. *"Advance"* is a specific ticket valid on booked train only, no change or refund. An *"Off peak"* or *"Anytime"* ticket is valid on any permitted train. You can buy an "Off Peak" ticket with a seat reservation for a specific train, but if you miss that train you can take any other "off peak" train (but you won't have a seat reservation - you'll have to find a vacant seat, or stand until one becomes available).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I will be arriving at LHR by flight. Suppose my flight scheduled arrival at LHR is 1 PM and I book ticket from London by 3 PM and flight arrives late in LHR and I miss the train/bus, do I get some refund from airlines?

**No.**  It's separate tickets, separate companies, and the airline will not reimburse you for costs of a new train ticket, unless there exists a special agreement.

Comment: Ok. Thanks.. what do you think is reasonable time to book a flight if scheduled arrival at lhr is 1PM

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik You mean to book a train?  Depending on the price difference, whether I'm travelling with luggage, and my passport.  You could book an off-peak ticket such that you can take any train for the rest of the day, or book a train at least three hours after your flight arrives.

Comment: Yes, I mean to book a train. I am travelling with luggage and my passport..

Comment: By passport, I meant that with an EU passport and automated ticket gates one probably needs much less time than with a non-EU passport and a visa.  Ultimately it's up to you how much financial risk you want to take.

Comment: Oh.. i am planning to book with a gap of 6 hours,, does that look ok?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Most probably yes.

Comment: I recommend booking an any time ticket. The difference between advanced (you can only take that train) and anytime is not that big. Actually, in the UK you can just show up and buy your train ticket on the spot. I wouldn't personally want to wait 6 hours for my pre-booked train and would just get a ticket on the day and jumped into the next leaving train.

Comment: @kiradotee I disagree.  At the time that the OP is travelling, an Off-Peak ticket will do. Anytime ticket Heathrow to Edinburgh costs £189.50, there are segments where Anytime costs 4× more than Off-Peak.  Only buy Anytime if you really must.

Comment: Sorry meant the off peak ticket. The peak anytime ticket is ridiculously expensive and it allows you to travel in the morning which is more useful to business people than OP. Yeah, off peak ticket.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly any missed train.

In Europe you may be entitled to delay compensation based on these rules:  https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm

However this has nothing to do with missing the train or not, the compensation is based on the amount of delay, not the consequences of it.

Comment: Ok. Thanks.. what do you think is reasonable time to book a flight if scheduled arrival at lhr is 1PM

Comment: Why do you keep asking that when you already have comments (on the question) telling you we need more information to say anything useful in that regard?

Comment: @Henrik can you delete your comment here. I have added details in my question.  If you think anything else is necessary, please ask below the question.